# Add view to another one programmatically inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

Something gone wrong on my code. I have an XML representing layout of my fragment (fragment_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

and another xml file representing a single view that shod go inside fragment layout (element.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how i fill Fragment layout inside onCreateView method:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,
            false);

    some_elements = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.some_array);

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < some_elements.length; i++) {

        View element = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.element, container, false);

        TextView tv= (TextView) element.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        prodotto.setText(prodotti[i]);

        EditText et= (EditText) element.findViewById(R.id.et);

        root.addView(element);

    }

    return view;
```

Now happen that only first element of "some_elements" array is showed inside fragment (element contains 10 elements). why other elements is not showed? what's wrong?

Comment: You can also wrap your root_layout in a scrollview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, in your RelativeLayout. It should be `wrap_content`

Comment: my mistake, thanks a lot. Too much job, for me, luckily it's friday!